# Yii: How to manage changelog for a model?

Tags: forms, yii, revision-history

```
CREATE TABLE `personchanges` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `msg` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `person` (`person`),
  KEY `fk_personchanges_1` (`person`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_personchanges_1` FOREIGN KEY (`person`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB COMMENT='changelog'
```

(There is also the table `person`, but its content is irrelevant for my question, just know that it has `id` field.)

In the editing form for `person` I want to display an (always initially empty) textarea.

If before saving (creation or updating) the user types a text in this textarea, this text should be saved into `personchanges` table.

When viewing (not editing) the person (from `person` table) among other data should be displayed `msg` from the last (having the highest `id`) `personchanges` row for the given person id.

My question: Where should I implement showing and editing the `msg` textarea? Should it be in the model (class `Person`), in the form, wherever?

Comment: Why don't you create another model as PersonChanges? and use it in your editing form. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/218/how-to-use-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models-cactiveform-and-ajax-validation-edition/ might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension performing kind of what you want: [Yii model Versioning](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/model-versioning/)

> SAModelVersioning is a Yii behavior that provides versioning
>   capabilities to any ActiveRecord object.

So you can track allt he changes on your model. The extension provides also some methods to get the last version, compare versions, revert to another version, ...